# Have philosophers identified what may cause something to be unknowable?

Tags: metaphysics, terminology

Have philosophers identified what may cause something to be unknowable? If such reasons have been identified, what are they called? If there's no exhaustive lists, what are the different causes or reasons that were identified for explaining or speculating on what may make something unknowable not by a particular person, but all person and absolutely?

Comment: This is related to the learner's paradox (or Meno's paradox). From the empiricist tradition (e.g., David Hume), you can only know what you can experience and sense. So "not being able to experience or sense something" is one of the reasons. Of course, in society, you can learn from other's experiences. So no one in the world should be able to sense the phenomenon and it must remain out of reach in the future. Of course, this answer depends on what knowledge is, in what case you may have a look at [the SEP conditions for knowledge](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/knowledge-analysis).

Comment: Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anamnesis_(philosophy), which is a slightly different articulation of the so called  "paradox"

Comment: See [Immanuel Kant on the limits of knowledge by Alsabeh](https://medium.com/@falsabeh/immanuel-kant-on-the-limits-of-knowledge-fe3e928ea644) for one classical analysis of the issue, and [Conversation's Human intelligence: have we reached the limit of knowledge?](https://theconversation.com/human-intelligence-have-we-reached-the-limit-of-knowledge-124819) for a modern natural science based take. "*As soon as you frame a question that you claim we will never be able to answer, you set in motion the very process that might well prove you wrong*", Dennett.